# How to test a computed property in VueJS using Mocha and Vue Test Utils

Tags: unit-testing, vue.js, mocha.js, vue-test-utils

In the following test, I have set my data object according to the [documentation](https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/api/wrapper-array/#setdata-data); however, "expiredListingsByWeek", which is a computed property that references "lastSaturdayNight" does not update when this occurs.

```
it ('returns an empty array when auctionDate > lastSaturdayNight', () => {
    wrapper = mount(adminResults, {
        propsData: {
            listings: [
                {
                    _id: "",
                    auctionDate: "2018-06-12T23:59:59.000Z",
                    contactTel: "",
                    results: {}
                }
            ]
        }
    });
    wrapper.setData({
        lastSaturdayNight: moment("2018-06-09T23:59:59.000Z")
    })
    expect(wrapper.vm.expiredListingsByWeek).toEqual([]);
});
```

**It is not clear if setData triggers a change event in the vue test utils documentation. Does it trigger a change event and if it doesn't, how should I test my computed property in my VueJS component? Additionally, are there any "gotchas" that I might be falling prey to?**

Comment: Could you please share the whole component? There's no change event in Vue. Vue uses getters and setters to make data properties reactive.

Comment: I'm having the same issue